# Como auto preencher uma fk no Laravel utilizando dados da sessão?

Tags: laravel

Tenho duas tabelas, **posts** e **users**. A tabela posts possui um relacionamento com a tabela users por meio da coluna **user_id**.

A questão é a seguinte: no controller estou utilizando um merge para preencher o user_id com o id do usuário. Gostaria de saber se é possível substituir este merge, talvez fazendo uso do método **user** (belongsTo) da model Post. Veja o código:

Controller:

```
$request->merge(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id]);
Post::create($request->all());
```

Model Post:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Comment: Deve dar, tenta: `Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());`. Precisas de ter no model user a relação `hasmany` com o model Post. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: Quando não tenho uma sessão estou recebendo o erro "Call to a member function posts() on null", porém, não estou conseguindo tratar isso com um if. Preciso conseguir identificar se o registro foi criado ou não

Comment: mas como fazias antes sem sessão? Que valor entrava no user id?

Comment: Me desculpe, utilizei as palavras de forma errada. Na verdade queria somente prevenir um erro, por exemplo, se por um acaso não existir sessão, cair em determinada condição. Para isso montei o seguinte if => (\Auth::user() && \Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all()))